# flutter app, list retrived from firestore duplicate it self

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, mobile, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function that is supposed to fetch me a list of Restaurants objects from firestore based on location.

the function does its job perfectly when i first run the app but after using the app from another device and updating resturants data in firestore documents, i somehow get duplicates of the restaurants list items.

here is the code for the function that fetch the the restaurants objects list:

```
Future<void> fetchRestaurantsList() async {
    try {
      Position position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition( 
          desiredAccuracy:
              Platform.isIOS ? LocationAccuracy.lowest : LocationAccuracy.high);
  
      final dbRestaurant = firestore
          .collection('testing')
          .document('users')
          .collection('restaurant');
          
      geo.collection(collectionRef: dbRestaurant)
          .within(
              center: GeoFirePoint(
                position.latitude,
                position.longitude
                  ),
              radius: 45.0,
              field: 'resturantLocation')
          .listen((event) {
        restaurantList.clear();       
       await event.forEach((element){

       final distance = Distance.getDistanceFromLatLonInKm( // calculating distance for each restaurant
              position.latitude,
              position.longitude,
              element.data['location']['geopoint'].latitude,
              element.data['location']['geopoint'].longitude)

          restaurantList.add(Restaurant( 
              id: element.documentID,
              logo: element.data['logo'],
              name: element.data['name'],
              distance: distance ,
              ));
             notifyListeners();
        });
        
      });             
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      }
    } finally {
      notifyListeners();
    }
     
  }
```

and this is the page that contains the list: (its under a parent widget which contains other tabs)

```
class RestruntsListTab extends StatefulWidget {
  final MainModel model;

  RestruntsListTab({@required this.model});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _RestruntsListTabState();
  }
}

class _RestruntsListTabState extends State<RestruntsListTab>
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    widget.model.fetchRestaurantsList();
    widget.model.checkLocationService().then((isActive) {
      if (isActive) {
      } else {
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text(
            language.enableLcation,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'eff', fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        ));
      }
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return ScopedModelDescendant<MainModel>(
      builder: (context, child, model) {
        return ListView.builder(
                     itemCount:model.restaurantList.length,
                     itemBuilder: (context,index) {
                                 return Row(
                                       children: <Widget>[
                                               Text(model.restaurantList[index].name),
                                               Text(model.restaurantList[index].distance),
                                               ],
                                       )
                              }
               );
                                     
   })
  }
}
```

this is a simplified code for demonstration but the actual code is pretty similar.
if you have encountered similar issues kindly share your experience.

thank you all.

Comment: Are the items duplicating in Firebase too ?

Comment: nope.its only duplicated in the restaurantList.

Comment: LoL, How did you manage this? Its really weird. I also have this problem and wasted a lot of my fresh time.

Answer (score 0):

check that fetchRestaurantsList() method is not called on widget build
or it is in StreamBuilder method...it's because  .listen((event) { this method it is like a stream so you have to use flag like bool variable to run the code inside it
if(mybool==false){// the other code goes.... setStste({mybool=true;})}

in this way it only excute the code once

Comment: it's only called on initState()method of the parent widget. the method is not called in widget build function nor in a streamBuilder.

Comment: i did  add a flag called onFirstRun to start the loop of getting the restaurants  only on first run, and also made an if statement to check if the element fetched exists in the list ,for each iteration of the for each loop. Still the issue is not solved :/

Answer (score 0):

There might be something wrong with the code, but I don't see it. What you can try doing is wrapping the content of `forEach` with

```
if(restaurantList.where((item) => item.id == element.documentID).isEmpty){
}
```

That should filter out duplicates.

Comment: I used the if statement to check if the element fetched exists in the list ,for each iteration of the for each loop. Still getting duplicates somehow

Comment: Well, that can only mean that their IDs are different, which is even weirder. Try using debug mode to put breakpoints and get closer to what's actually happening, like in the `forEach` call.